# How to migrate a public library view from one library into another

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-views

From SharePoint Online, I was able to go into Site Settings, create my custom content type, and add new columns to it.

I then created a new SharePoint site, added my custom columns from my custom content type and saved a public view for my library in this site.

I then created a new library within the same site, and added my columns to it (from my custom content type), **but how do we copy over the public view that was in the previous library into this new library?**

In this case, does the view *have to be* re-created when going from library to library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to copy the public view from one library to another library.

You need to re-create a new public view in the new document library.

Comment: Ok, I can at least know in confidence, which will need be trained to end-users who create multiple libraries.  Many thanks!